# angular-g-recaptcha not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I am using angular-g-recaptcha but it is not working in my project, i will explain.

I configured in google recaptcha my key and domain (localhost).

But my recaptcha never appeared in the screen.

I am using provider method to set the key and settings:

```
angular
  .module('gitlocalApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngResource',
  'wo.grecaptcha'
])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$grecaptchaProvider) {

    $grecaptchaProvider.set({
    sitekey: '6LfchhoTAAAAAKdo9FfSOS90mER-PnDDmqpKPPTq',  
    theme: 'Light',                                       
    type: 'image',                                        
    size: 'NORMAL',
      ...
    });
});
```

I am using the directive in this way:

```
<div>
    <div 
    grecaptcha="{sitekey: '===KEY===', theme: 'dark'}"

    data-ng-model="response" gre-info="info">
    Loading...
    </div>
    <div data-ng-bind="respone"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note from [Documentation](https://github.com/paunin/angular-g-recaptcha)

> Keep in mind that the captcha only works when used from a **real domain**
>   and with a valid re-captcha key, so this file wont work if you just
>   load it in your browser.

Comment: This is strange, because the google documentation talks By default, all keys work on "localhost" (or "127.0.0.1"), so you can always develop and test on your local machin

Comment: I am trying the angular-no-captcha [link](https://github.com/CodeDistillery/angular-no-captcha) and I can run in localhost